# Trying to use Chromedriver to type into some fields and click a button - Getting a timeout

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Chromedriver in Python to type a username and password into a page then followed by clicking sign in, but I'm having some trouble.
Here's what I've got, down to the username field

```
driver = Chrome(chrome_path)
URL = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/login"
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input"""))) 
elem.send_keys(username)
```

But I'm getting an error

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to locate the "username" input field. In order to do so, you need to first switch to the iframe that contains that element.

Try this:

```
driver = Chrome(chrome_path)
URL = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/login"
driver.get(URL)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#disneyid-iframe))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="email"]'))) 
elem.send_keys(username)
```

Comment: Terrific, that did the trick, thanks! Where do you find the name of the frame that's needed to switch to?

Comment: I inspected element on the "username" field, then scrolled up the DOM, looking at each parent element until I found the iframe, then I used its `id` attribute to locate it.